# How to manage concurrency by field with eventsourcing

Tags: c#, concurrency, cassandra, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am new to eventsourcing, so this might be a dreadfully incompetent question, so please bear with me:

We have an eventsourced, cqrs system with cassandra for persistance. We have a sequence/version number to handle conflicting modifications on an aggregate.

We need a readmodel for an administrative interface, that needs to display quite a few details from several bounded contexts and make it available for editing via a rest api.

What is the best practice handling concurrency in this readmodel. Thougts are the following:

1) 
It would be nice to have a clean readmodel including all relevant data, that we can get with one request. This raises the problem: When multiple fields can be independently be edited, how do we actually create this readmodel guaranteeing that we handle the sequence for all fields? Could we add a sequence number per field and handle that somehow, but that will totally clutter our readmodel.

2)
We could have a readmodel per field making everything easy in theory, but creating a lot of requests, which would be generally stupid, but easy to manage.

3) 
We could create a sequence-table seperate to the readmodel and keep track that way having both a general sequence and a per-field-sequence, and the use that to write a new readmodel when necessary.

Any thoughts.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of concurrency conflict in your case?

Answer (score 1):

We use strict event ordering, each event having an aggregate version inside it as metadata. We also have one, single-threaded projection. This guarantees that there will be no overrides.

The question arises about the scalability of such system and so far we have not hit the limits with this approach but the day might come. Daniel's suggestion to keep the aggregate version together with the read model makes sense but again, it will fail when scaling, assuming you will need competing consumers that will try updating your model simultaneously.

As we know, ordering is an issue with competing consumers, so I don't really have a ready-made answer for this. If the chance of concurrent update for the same field will be real (not just hypothetical), I would also consider field-level read models and UI composition.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption in a CQRS ES based system is that you/the user doesn't edit read models directly. Read models are the result of all relevant events in the event stream, ie a projection. Therefore, read models change as a result of events which were caused as a result of commands.

In order to handle concurrency in that scenario, I favour using a version number stored against read models.  When you form a command it should include the version of the read model table that was used to supply the context for the command.

You can then check that the events being raised have the right number. If not you can throw a concurrency exception. OR you can create a concurrency resolver service. This would check to see if the events which happened since your command was issues actually conflict or not.

If you want to know more about concurrency management in an event sourced system you can check out this post:

[Handling Concurrency Conflicts in a CQRS and Event Sourced System](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/09/29/handling-concurrency-issues-cqrs-event-sourced-system/)

Hope that helps.